# How to create the LWUIT 3D carousel

Tags: java-me, lwuit, carousel

Do anyone know on how to create 3d carousel effect in LWUIT?. Can anyone explain me with a sample program on how to implement?.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, I'm considering you want to use Lists, that's the most sensible way to do it, isn't is?

The first thing you want to know is this `List.setFixedSelection(List.FIXED_CENTER)`, and that's the easy part. Tha method makes the list scroll around the middle displayed element, it's to say, it will add the carousel effect.

The difficult part comes when adding the 3D. First ad all, you should have a look to [this article](http://codenameone.blogspot.com/2008/07/lwuit-list-renderer-by-chen-fishbein.html), if you haven't done it yet. It's compulsory to understand how LWUIT Lists work and what you can do (and how) with them. Basically you would need to implement a [`ListCellRenderer`](http://lwuit.java.net/nonav/javadocs/index.html) and specially the `getListCellRendererComponent(List list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected)`, there you would have to add the corresponding logic to detect where the list element is going to be painted, and play with the Styles to set shadows, gradients, or whatever you want.

And I'm sorry but I don't have any sample for you, maybe you can have a look at [Shai's Blog](http://codenameone.blogspot.com/), I don't know whether there is that specific sample, but there are a lot of them.

Good luck and regards.